# Run shell script via PHP

Tags: php, bash, magento, exec

Is there a way to run the following script via PHP

http://www.magentoadvisor.com/magento-backup/tutorial-magento-backup-scripts-part-2/

I have tried to use exec, shell_exec, system but none of them are working. They do work when I try exec('whois domain.com') though so it must be something I am doing wrong!!

If this is not possible does anyone know of a good way of backuping up Magento via PHP, unfortuantely I don't have SSH access.

Thanks

UPDATE
This is the code I am trying to use

```
system('magento-backup-script.bin -date', $output); 
var_dump($output);
```

Output: int(127)

Php safe mode is off

**UPDATE:**

I managed to get i working by copy the script into the PHP file and use the tactics operator to run the command. Thanks for all your help everyone

Comment: if the user running your apache version / php has no access to run that script, it will not run. Check file ownership / permissions. Remember when you run an exec() you run under permissions of the application user.

Comment: system('magento-backup-script.bin -date', $output); 
   var_dump($output);

Comment: did you `chmod` the file to 755, if not try and do that first.

Comment: is this running through Apache/mod-php?  And if you don't have SSH access, what are you using to upload to this host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) to execute commands on the system, for example:

If your string is called **backup** and is located in **/home/rob/scripts/backup/megento** you can issue the command like so:

```
if(false === ($line = system("/home/rob/scripts/backup/megento/backup",$result)))
{
    echo "Error " . (int)$result . ": Backup failed: (" .  $line . ")\n";
}
```

if your getting the result **127**, this is known as an exit code, int 127 usually means that the bas script attempted to execute a command but the command was not found.

looking at the bash script it uses the *tar* command to create the archive, have you made sure tar exists and is installed on the server.

you may also want to pipe the output to an error log to see what's happening:

```
system("/home/rob/scripts/backup/megento/backup >> results.txt");
echo file_get_contents("/home/rob/scripts/backup/megento/results.txt");
```

or if that is leading to an empty file maybe its a perms problem, try the following:

```
exec("/home/rob/scripts/backup/megento/backup",$full_result);
var_dump($full_results);// Array I believe.
```

Comment: added the exec attempt, this will trap *all* data from the terminal so you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Use system() command of PHP.

> system() is just like the C version of
>   the function in that it executes the
>   given command and outputs the result.
>
> The system() call also tries to
>   automatically flush the web server's
>   output buffer after each line of
>   output if PHP is running as a server
>   module.
>
> If you need to execute a command and
>   have all the data from the command
>   passed directly back without any
>   interference, use the passthru()
>   function.

([From the PHP manual: system](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your webhost has safe mode enabled which blocks you calling `system()`. Upload a php file to your webserver containing the following code then link to it here (or if the server is not publicly accessible put it on DropBox or somewhere). This will tell us what functions are disabled on your hosting / if safemode is turned on.

```
<?php 
  phpinfo();
?>
```